# writing an audio player

Tags: audio, signal-processing

I'm currently writing an audio player for mac using ffmpeg. I followed the tutorial

http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/

The tutorial is a bit out of date(for example it used avcodec_decode_audio2,which has already been removed from the ffmpeg library),the player worked, but i did't understand the code very well,especially the concepts and the process behind those APIs.

So I am thinking about learning more about this subject. How can I get systematic knowledge about audio programming? Do I need to study digital signal processing? Are there any books for beginners?